# Vinyl: compose record type aliases

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation, vinyl

In Vinyl, I can define a type alias for a record to make it easier to export to other modules:

```
import Data.Vinyl

name = Field :: "name" ::: String
age = Field :: "age" ::: Int
type Person = ["name" ::: String, "age" ::: Int]
```

Now suppose I add another field storing height.

```
height = Field :: "height" ::: Int
```

I would like to nicely construct a type alias for the record containing a `Person` and `height`. Naively, that might look something like this:

```
type MeasuredPerson = ("height" ::: Int) : Person
```

This syntax doesn't work, obviously! Is there a way to do this? Are there any good references that explain the type-level array syntax that seems to be in use here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out there's a very easy answer to this which I managed to miss:

`Data.Vinyl.Rec` defines both cons and append for type level lists, so the following works:

```
type MeasuredPerson = ("height" ::: Int) ': Person
```

If I had two lists, I could append them as follows:

```
type Other = Person ++ Address
```

Comment: Actually, it only defines `++`, `':` and `'[]` come with `-XDataKinds`.